# How to delay installer exec after a restart until after it's own virtual iso mounts?

Tags: windows-10, iso-image, installer

I am trying to install software from an ISO image.
Due to lack of persistence of a mounted ISO image after restart in win10, I am using the 3rd party freeware *Virtual CloneDrive* to provide persistence of the ISO image after restart.
However, the software controlling the install executes (after the restart) before the ISO has remounted.
Result: the install fails because it's installation media is "no longer there" (not mounted yet.)
This specific ISO is a bit over 9 gigs, so it cannot be written to physical media.

So, any idea how to delay the installer? Some way to make Virtual CloneDrive load and mount sooner, before the installer?

Comment: I would want to find out how both these competing processes start and if they can be shifted.  For example, how does the software controlling the install run at boot?  Can this be moved later?  Finding which can moved earlier/later is probably the key here.  You may need to run Process Monitor to grab a boot trace to fathom this.  Possibly AutoRuns before you reboot as I assume the startup method written by the controlling software will have already written out its startup item, e.g. the Run key?  Scheduled Task?  I'm thinking before the reboot, you might be able to adjust this startup item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this from wonkey_monkey:

Before the reboot have a look in the registry to see what command has been queued up to run - it's probably in one of:

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

Copy and save the command, delete it, reboot, mount, and then run the command from the Run box (or you might have to make a shortcut of it and Run As Administrator)